# How can only one line be drawn through 4 collinear points?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

There are 10 points in a plane no three of which are in the same straight line except 4 points, which are collinear. Find the probability that the number of straight lines obtained from the pairs of these points.

Given solution: total lines between 10 non collinear points = $^{10}C_2$ = 45

total lines between 4 non collinear points = $^{4}C_2$ = 6

Since the 4 points are non collinear and **only one line can be drawn through all four**:

Total lines possible = $45 - 6 + 1 = 40$

My doubt: if I were to mark the 4 collinear points as a, b , c ,d then can’t I draw more than one line such as ab, bc, cd, bd etc? So how come can only one line be drawn?
Also the question asks for the probability which would be possible outcomes divided by total outcomes so how come is this the correct solution? Isn’t this just the possible outcomes?

Comment: What's the difference between a line and a line segment?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche  oh okay yes that makes sense but the question still doesn’t specify a random experiment so how do I get the total outcomes to calculate probability? Is the question just wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1:As how you said,ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd are the same line because the points are collinear.

Part 2:Yes you are right.The question doesn't imply randomness.It asks "Find the probability that the number of straight lines obtained from the pairs of these points" and it is either wrong or incomplete

Comment: Oh okay so the question’s wrong thank you very much!